# Facebook authentication in firebase not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

What I'm trying to do is login with Facebook using Firebase and then get name, email, profile picture and uid and then store it to Firebase Database.

Everything is working fine until clicking on login button and then the Facebook account window pop up. After that, when I select an account by clicking "*Continue With Rishabh*", nothing happens.

No authentication, no error, nothing. Same Facebook account selection window stays on screen and nothing happens.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my SignInActivity.java:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };

        mSignInToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.signInToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mSignInToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mRef.keepSynced(true);

        mEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passowrdField);
        mSigninBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signinBtn);
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        // Initialize Facebook Login button
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                // ...
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
        mProgress.setMessage("Logging in...");
        mProgress.show();

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mProgress.dismiss();
                        }else{
                            String uid=task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                            String name=task.getResult().getUser().getDisplayName();
                            String email=task.getResult().getUser().getEmail();
                            String image=task.getResult().getUser().getPhotoUrl().toString();

                            DatabaseReference childRef = mRef.child(uid);
                            childRef.child("name").setValue(name);
                            childRef.child("email").setValue(email);
                            childRef.child("image").setValue(image);

                            mProgress.dismiss();

                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(mainIntent);


                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Have you find out what the problem was?

Comment: Yes, you just need to change some default permission in facebook developer page.

Comment: please, I need some help on this same issue. Could you please explain the solution a little bit more?

Comment: @JorgeGabrielSiqueira  check below i explained properly my solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See what all you need to do is to change some permission in facebook developer page. See the below picture make sure you too make required permission "Yes" as I did : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Put this in the Application.

Comment: Create a new class `YourAppNameApplication` extending `Application`. Override onCreate, put the code there.  
In your manifest.xml, under `<application>` put `android:name="YourAppNameApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by running the application in a real device (not in the emulator).