# Facebook Authentication in firebase not working on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I want to login with Facebook using Firebase.

Everything is working fine until clicking on login button and then the Facebook account window pop up. After that, when I select an account by clicking "Continue With ......", nothing happens.

No authentication, no error, nothing. the Facebook account selection window disappear and nothing happens.

I found that i should activate all the permissions in the Facebook Developers page, but it stays the same problem ..

this is MainActivity.java :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        RelativeLayout loginButton = findViewById(R.id.facebookContinue);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("email","public_profile"));
                LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);    
                      handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                        // ...
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                        // ...
                    }
                });

            }
        });

}


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

and those are my dependecies :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    // materail io
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Firebase SDK
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

    //Firebase auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'

    //Google sign-in
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    //Facebook Login
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'


}
```

and this is my facebook developer page

[image: Facebook developer page]

like i said before .. i activate all the permissions in facebook developer page and it still the same problem

Comment: have you added your key hash on facebook developer console

Comment: @KishanMaurya Yes sir!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook authentication in firebase not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166708/facebook-authentication-in-firebase-not-working)

Comment: I tried it but also not working ..

Comment: Have you added facebook_app_id in the manifest? @YoussefIslem

Comment: @BrahmaDatta Yes sir!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the app and re run it again and i found that the hash key was wrong .. so i wrote the correct one and everything became great

Comment: Great. There might be chances of getting these kinds of issues when anyone won't upload the google-services.json file, facebook app ids or hash key.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (I think). No errors. But then I checked the logcat and I found a "ERR_PERMISSION_DENIED" error. Tried a lot of things but the thing that worked out was uninstalling and reinstalling the app on my emulator. Don't know why, but I got that from the answer above.

For anyone facing this issue try this simple solution and hope it works.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. I have the depencancies set up, oAuth links, key hashes etc. But once I click continue with... it just loads forever. My code is consistant with the guide for firebase auth ui. I did notice some errors in logcat though:

```
{HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token type.}
E  Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
E  Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
W  Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. 
W  Cleared Reference was only reachable from finalizer (only reported once)
```

I also updated the manifest with the query providers as logcat suggested.
I have also tried to run it on a real device and deleting the app and running it again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).